# How or where to specify omx decoder supports tunneling

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, openmax

The BSP supports tunneling of Hw accelerated codec.
Android uses `feature-tunneled-playback` to check if tunneling is supported.
If yes It will try to configure tunneling.
How to implement or specify the android extension `OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode`

[It](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/native/include/media/hardware/HardwareAPI.h#220) just says for tunneled playback support the extension should be supported. How to expose this extension so that android will assume the tunneling is supported ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to set

```
<Feature name="feature-tunneled-playback" />
```

in desired codec in media_codecs.xml